# Make modal in bootstrap 5 with vuejs3 like in material-ui

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, vue-composition-api

I'm starting a to-do project with VueJS 3 and Bootstrap 5. I created a component customModal, where I need it to create and update a toDo (title and description). The problem is that the modal can be opened in other components where it is not even imported. I couldn't find a way to make the modal behave like in react and material UI (using state to open it) and using condition to make it known that we are creating or updating.

main.js

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'

createApp(App).use(bootstrap).mount('#app')
```

customModal.vue, Here I'm making the modal appear by default but this is not working

```
<template>
  <div
    class="modal"
    id="exampleModalCenter"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
    aria-hidden="true"
    data-bs-backdrop="static"
    v-show="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Create New Todo {{ msg }}</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
            @click="handleDismissModal"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="exampleFormControlInput1"
              placeholder="Enter title"
              v-model="todoItem.title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Description</label>
            <textarea
              class="form-control"
              id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
              rows="3"
              placeholder="Description..."
              v-model="todoItem.description"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            @click="handleNewTodo"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          >
            Save changes
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

toDoPage.vue : the mainPage

```
<script>
...
// variable who will contain the toDo
const todoList = ref([])

const getItemToEdit = (pos) => {
  update.value = true
}

const closeModal = () => {
  update.value = false
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex mt-4">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter"
      >
        Create new todo
      </button>
      <CustomModal
        :addNewItem="addNewItem"
        :update="update"
        :closeModal="closeModal"
      />
    </div>
     // display here all to-do list , with button delete & edit for each other
     <CustomList
      :todoList="todoList"
      :deleteTodoItem="deleteTodoItem"
      :getItemToEdit="getItemToEdit"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

customList.vue, where the modal is opened without being imported. and not giving me a way to make the customModal know that we are currently updating here and not creating anymore.

```
<script setup>
import DeleteIcon from '../Icon/DeleteIcon.vue'
import EditIcon from '../Icon/EditIcon.vue'

const { todoList, deleteTodoItem, getItemToEdit } = defineProps([
  'deleteTodoItem',
  'updateTodoStatus',
  'getItemToEdit'
])
const deleteItem = (pos) => {
  deleteTodoItem(pos)
}
const updateStatus = (pos) => {
  updateTodoStatus(pos)
}
const handleEdit = (pos) => {
  getItemToEdit(pos)
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="row g-4">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in todoList" :key="index">
      <h2>{{ item?.title }}</h2>
      <p class="text-justify">
        {{ item?.description }}
      </p>
      <div class="icon-link">
        <button
          class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
          data-bs-toggle="modal"
          data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter"
          @click="handleEdit(index)"
        >
          <EditIcon />
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2 btn-sm" @click="deleteItem(index)">
          <DeleteIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried to set v-show = showModal on the modal where showModal= ref(true) not working, then I set it by default to v-show= true by default, which is not working as well.

What I'm expecting is that my customModal won't be opened in other components where its not imported.
like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';

const style = {
  position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

export default function BasicModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Text in a modal
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```